# Trigger pra atualizar estoque

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, trigger

Estou tentando criar uma `trigger` para atualizar meu estoque de produtos, quando o status da minha compra estiver fechado (CF = Compra Fechada).

Porém, ele está me emitindo um erro, e eu não consegui identificar o que esta fazendo este erro ser gerado. Alguém tem alguma dica ?

```
O erro é Erro(3,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Erro(3,70): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NEW"."IDCOMPRA": identificador inválido
Erro(6,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Erro(6,99): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NEW"."IDPRODUTO": identificador inválido
```

O que eu fiz:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ATUALIZA_ESTOQUE BEFORE INSERT ON ITEMCOMPRA FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE SITUACAOCOMPRA CHAR(2); 

BEGIN
    SELECT SITUACAOCOMPRA INTO SITUACAOCOMPRA FROM COMPRA WHERE ID = NEW.IDCOMPRA;
    IF(SITUACAOCOMPRA = 'CF') THEN  
    --BEGIN
      UPDATE PRODUTO SET QUANTIDADEPRODUTO = QUANTIDADEPRODUTO + NEW.QUANTIDADEPRODUTO WHERE ID = NEW.IDPRODUTO;   
    --END;
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Está faltando identificar a variavel da trigger, asssim:

:NEW (faltou os dois pontos)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ATUALIZA_ESTOQUE BEFORE INSERT ON ITEMCOMPRA 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE SITUACAOCOMPRA CHAR(2); 

BEGIN
    SELECT SITUACAOCOMPRA INTO SITUACAOCOMPRA FROM COMPRA WHERE ID = :NEW.IDCOMPRA;
    IF(SITUACAOCOMPRA = 'CF') THEN  
    --BEGIN
      UPDATE PRODUTO SET QUANTIDADEPRODUTO = QUANTIDADEPRODUTO + :NEW.QUANTIDADEPRODUTO WHERE ID = :NEW.IDPRODUTO;   
    --END;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: ele me retorna Erro(6,67): PLS-00049: variável de ligação 'NEW.QUANTIDADEPRODUTO' inválida

Comment: estranho, a trigger aparentemente está correta. tenta referenciar new e old conforme a minha alteração. Se não der, tente armazenar esse valor em uma variável mais acima e trocar o update pra utilizar ela no set.

Comment: não, ele persiste

Comment: Editei ali, pois o FOR ficou na linha do create, porém ele deve ir no FOR EACH ROW ficando REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW e apagando da linha de cima

Comment: eu mesmo já havia arrumado isso, ele persistiu assim mesmo

Comment: No mais acredito que a trigger está correta, deve ser problema com a tabela

Comment: galera resolvi, era alguns detalhes no ID!

Comment: @Mateus esse tipo de edição que você fez é desencorajada, nunca altere códigos ou detalhes que mudem o sentido do post do autor, sempre deixe um comentário ao inves disso.

Comment: sim, a trigger está correta, verifique se na tabela o campo está exatamente com esse nome QUANTIDADEPRODUTO. para fazer um teste, remova essa variável que esta sinalizando o erro.